# Is it possible to do a silent install when it includes Kernel Mode Driver?

Tags: kernel, sign, drivers

So I have an issue that I am trying to understand and solve.  I need to know if it is possible to build an installer(msi) that I can perform a silent install(/qn) via SCCM.  I do not need to know the SCCM part per-say but I am to provide an installer that will be pushed out with SCCM.

Now here is the issue.  I have the installer built and I think the kernel mode driver is signed correctly, but when trying to install in Win7/8 the install goes up till I get a prompt alerting me of the driver install.  It shows my cert info, but I still have to allow it to proceed and thus it has to be attended.  Is there away around this?

I have been able to do what I want by adding my .cer file to a machines certificate store, but in talking with the individual this is for this was frowned upon.  I indicated the plan was to add it and then remove it after the install.  What are thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If MS allows people to silently install kernel mode drivers then I'm off to Unix.

Comment: This was a project that I inherited and was told that this was possible.  I was pretty sure you can do it if you go through Microsoft's certification process for drivers, but did not think it was possible with just a kernel-mode cert.  Thus why I am asking.  As stated I was able to add my cert file to the certificate store via command line and it worked as wanted.  So as stated I was going to do a custom action to put it in the store install then delete it but again the customer was against that and I just need to make sure there is no other way than those two.